# A letter is missed in Russian words to be searched in VIM

Tags: scripting, vim, search

When I run:

```
$ vim -s <(printf '/конфедерация')
```

VIM opens and shows `'/конфедерция'` in the left bottom corner without `'а'`.
Why?

There is no problem with `'/стол'` for example. But if the word is a little longer then a letter is missed. No problems with long words in English.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

Terminal VIM
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:43:18)
Included patches: 1-52
Extra patches: 8.0.0056

$ locale
LANG=en_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8

Konsole (Version 2.13.2)

$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this on OpenBSD 6.0 running Vim 8.0.95.

Comment: Can reproduce with Ubuntu 16.04 with Vim 7.4.1689. So seems to be a bug that was fixed in the meantime.

Comment: What locales are you using?  What terminal?  What `$TERM`?  Terminal Vim or gVim?

Comment: @SatoKatsura xterm. But I think the problem is in VIM as printf prints the word completely.

Comment: So, why do you think the other information I was asking for is irrelevant to Vim?

Comment: @SatoKatsura I've added the missing info to the question

Comment: I reckon @taketwo is on the right track. I also replicated this on Cent OS 7, running Vim 7.4.160.

Comment: @SatoKatsura So many questions, but any suggestions? Are you from VIM team? I cannot update to another VIM. When I run sudo apt-get update it doesn't show me new versions.

Comment: _any suggestions?_ - Sure: try the latest version, and see if it solves the problem. If it does, do a `git bisect` to find out when it was fixed. If it doesn't, post a bug report to `vim_dev`. You don't need to update your system's Vim for that, you can compile it in your `$HOME`.